# OSX gatekeeper not reject third party app

Tags: code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I have built my java application as .app bundle for mac os with simple script to run my jar file.

I have sign code with command `codesign -s "My company" my-app`

Verify with `codesign --verbose=4 my-app` and get

```
myapp: valid on disk
myapp: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Verify with `spctl -a -t exec myapp`

```
myapp.app: rejected
```

But i still can run myapp on mac machine without error message.
How can I make gatekeeper reject my app and show message as unidentified developer or something like that?. I have set gatekeeper only allow app from App Store, but gatekeeper not work